# Reactive Forms - How to fix AbstractControl error?

Tags: angular, formarray

I have the following definitions for a FromArray: `manageIds!: FormArray`

I use the following function to generate the form controls dynamically in the HTML:

```
getControl(form: FormArray, index: number, controlName: string): FormControl {
   return (form.at( index ) as FormArray).get(controlName) as FormControl;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="getControl(manageIds, id,'nameXXX')"
       [value]="id" id="user_{{id}}">
</mat-checkbox>
```

All works fine. But When I try to user this definition:

```
this.generalForm = new FormGroup({
    formXXX: this.fb.array([]) as FormArray,
    formYYY: this.fb.array([]) as FormArray,
});
```

and implement the same function: `getControl(....)` for `formXXX` in HTML as:

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="getControl(generalForm.controls['formXXX'], id,'nameXXX')"
       [value]="id" id="user_{{id}}">
</mat-checkbox>
```

I face the known error regarding: `AbstractControl`:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormArray'.
> Type 'AbstractControl<any, any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormArray': controls, at, push, insert, and 5 more.

How can I fix this so that it also works for: `formXXX` which is also of type `formArray`?

I have been searching and found couple of questions about this topic. The Fix is to use a separated function like the one I'm already using: `getControl(...)`.

Comment: Would suggest writing a getter for retrieve `generalForm.controls['formXXX']` as FormArray. Then you can call the getter in `getControl` method

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Sorry for late reply, can you specify what is not working by providing the infoerror details? Thanks

Comment: @YongShun, It throws same error I mentioned in my question. Thanks! Somehow it should work, but I just cannot get the fix. Thanks!